# How do I route a specific ip address via the default system gateway?

Tags: iptables, route, gateway, wireguard

I send all the traffic through a Wireguard VPN, but I need to setup an exception. Packets directed to my own public IP have to go through the default gateway of the system.

It works as intended if I add this to the kernel routes:
`route add X.X.X.X gw 192.168.1.254`.
But, of course, here I'm hardcoding my router's gateway and it won't work if I'm connected to any other network. How can I generalize this behaviour so that I always send packets directed to X.X.X.X through the default gateway? Perhaps using iptables rather than adding kernel routes would be better?

Comment: Your computer cannot guess the gateway's IP on its own: either you set it yourself (static configuration that you did), or you get it dynamically using DHCP, and the default route will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable:

`defaultGW=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')`

then:

`route add X.X.X.X gw $defaultGW`

---

Perhaps you should start using `ip route`, it's the modern alternative to `route`.

Comment: Thank you, works as intended! Only minor problem is that for some reason networkmanager's wireguard plugin ignores the commands if I use them as PreUp/PostDown directives, whereas wireguard's own cli works like a charm, but I guess it's a problem with nm.

I will look into ip route, thanks for the tip!